# What is the maximum file size allowed on SharePoint online site?

Tags: sharepoint-online

What is the default size?

What is the maximum file size allowed on SharePoint online site?

Is there any upper limitation and how to increase it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

15GB is the maximum size of file supported.

Files attached to list items can be up to 250 MB in size.

These restrictions are out of the box and you can't change those.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498