# As an End User how can one find the maximum allowable file size in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

As an end user in a an organization how can one find what is the maximum file size allowed on the sharepoint?

The limit seems to be custom set as i followed the following 2 answers:
1 - Question [814](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/814/maximum-file-upload-size-in-sharepoint-2010)
2 - Question [228612](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228612/what-is-the-maximum-file-size-allowed-on-sharepoint-online-site)

I have a file that is greater than 50 MB. 
[image: 50 MB].

But also i am not able to upload the file of size 155 MB 
[image: 155 MB]. 
That is less than the default size of 250 MB.

**So as an end user** how can i know what is the maximum file size i can work with?

Answer (score 0):

**For SharePoint 2010 on-premises:**

By default, the maximum upload size is 50 MB (the maximum can be 2 GB). The default maximum file size is 250 MB.  The “maximum upload size” and “maximum file” are different.

There is a table lists the recommended guidelines for lists and libraries in [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits). For more information, see [Designing large Lists and maximizing list performance (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=105580).

Navigate to Central Administration -> Manage web applications -> High-light the web application -> Click on “General Settings” on the ribbon -> Check the Maximum Upload Size.

Increase the Maximum Upload Size.

A blog about how to [increase the SharePoint 2010 Upload File Size Limit](https://angler.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/increase-the-sharepoint-2010-upload-file-size-limit/)

**For SharePoint Online:**

Less than 15 GB per file. It cannot be changed.

[SharePoint Online Limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-online-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498)

Comment: As an end user would I have access to the central administration? Question is more from end user perspective. Shouldn't this thing be made visible to the end user in some way or the other?

Comment: It can only be accessed by admin. For normal users, as an alternative, you can put a text as a reminder on the page to let them know the max uploaded file size.

Comment: I am sorry to ask you again. Where to put the text as a reminder? I dont have any option to go to the administrative panel. Not even for the site space that i am currently using.

Comment: As you don't have permissions, you need to ask admin for the size limit. "add text as reminder" means user who knows the size limit can add a text on the library view page to let others know the limit. Based on your scenario, I think you still need to contact with admin to get the limit.